# Algorithm of inserting android contact to SQL database

Tags: android, sql, sms

I need advise... 
My app working with contacts, who have correspondence (SMS dialogs).

I have some difficulties with optimization getting process.
I decided realize that scheme:

1. On first launch read all *"content://sms/inbox"* and add unique value (broup by number of contact) to array new String [n.count()][4]. (fiedls: name, number, date, message and type)
2. Sort array as I want and transmit to main activity (or i can read db table directly there it doesn't matter)
3. Main activity class has procedure, which fill ListView *(list.setAdapter)* from receive data.

Everything works at the emulator perfectly, but when I trying setup at real device app catch fatal error.

So after aforesaid I have 2 quesions:
1. Why app is crashing? (any ideas)
2. How I can fix / rebuild my algorithm. Any pertinent criticism. I need function, which display in ListView contacts, "-" if contact does not have any incoming SMS, message of SMS if they exist.

Thanks.

below you can see procedures which insert and read data from db. 
I will repeat, **everything works at the emulator perfectly.** It means db created, tables created and data insert, read and update. I public code "for a full picture".

```
public void Contact_to_db () {
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" ), null, null, null, "DATE ASC");

    int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.BODY );
    int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.ADDRESS );
    int indexDate = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.DATE );

    if ( indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst() ) return;

    String sender = "";
    String number = "";
    String message = "";
    String type = "";

    do {    
        sender = "";
        message = "";
        type = "";
        number = cursor.getString( indexAddr );

        if (getContactDisplayNameByNumber(cursor.getString( indexAddr )).equals("")) 
            sender = cursor.getString( indexAddr );
        else 
            sender = getContactDisplayNameByNumber(cursor.getString( indexAddr ));

        message = cursor.getString( indexBody );

        SQLiteDatabase db_read = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db_read.query(dbHelper.USER_TABLE, null, "number like " + number , null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) 
                    //fiend...
            else {
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sender);
                    boolean look = matcher.lookingAt();

                    if (look)
                        type = "1";
                    else
                        type = "0";

                    SQLiteDatabase db_whrite = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put("name", sender);
                    cv.put("number", number);
                    cv.put("msg", message);
                    cv.put("date", cursor.getString( indexDate ));
                    cv.put("type", type);
                    db_whrite.insert(dbHelper.USER_TABLE, null, cv);
                    db_whrite.close();

                }
                c.close();
                db_read.close();
            }
        }

    while( cursor.moveToNext() );
    cursor.close();
    dbHelper.close();
   }
```

read and fill...

```
public void UpdateTableRows() {     
    SMSDataCollection = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String,String> map = null;
    String message = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db_read = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db_read.query(dbHelper.USER_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    prmax = c.getCount();
    cnt = 0;
    pbCount.setMax(prmax-1);
    pbCount.setProgress(0);

    int i = 0;
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            message = c.getString(3);
            if (!(message.equals(""))) {
                if ((message.substring(0, 2).equals("SM")) && (message.length()>6)) {
                    try {
                    String CutMsg = message.substring(message.indexOf('|')+1, message.length());
                    String key = message.substring(2, message.indexOf('|'));

                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(key);
                    boolean look = matcher.lookingAt();

                    if (look)
                        message = StringCryptor.decrypt(CutMsg, Integer.parseInt(key));

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(); }
                } else 
                    message = StringCryptor.decrypt(message, uPassword); 
            }

            if (message.length() > 25) 
                message = message.substring(0, 24) + "...";

            map = new HashMap<String,String>();                 
            map.put(KEY_SENDER,         c.getString(1));
            map.put(KEY_NUMBER,         c.getString(2));
            map.put(KEY_MESS,           message);

            if (c.getString(4).equals("0")) 
                map.put(KEY_ICON, "person_icon_a");
            else
                map.put(KEY_ICON, "person_icon_f");

            SMSDataCollection.add(map);

            h.post(updateProgress);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    c.close();
    db_read.close();
    dbHelper.close();

    final BinderData bindingData = new BinderData(this,SMSDataCollection);


    list.post(new Runnable(){
         public void run() {
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SMSList);
            list.setAdapter(bindingData);
            list.setEnabled(true);
            //pbCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pbRound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            img_update.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
 }
```

Comment: crash ? post stacktrace

Comment: how can I get it?....

Comment: srsly ? you have written all this and you have no idea how to get a stacktrace ? (|puzzled|) go to the logcat view, or run adb logcat if you don't use eclipse or android studio, run your app, see the result

Comment: I don't know how get stacktrace from real device...
I wrote "everything works at the emulator perfectly"

Comment: check the debugging options on the device, plug it to your computer, run the app, get the stacktrace

Comment: In android settings check "debugging from USB"... Connect to pc... Run app - get error... But where i can find log?

Comment: same as when you run on the emulator. if using eclipse, open the ddms perspective, in the devices tab, select your device, you'll have the log in the logcat view

Comment: Thanks for help, but I can't make it work! 
I found some guides about using DDMS. 
I use eclipse. When device connected I launch eclipse. Where is no any devices into tab DDMS / devices...

[2013-09-13 14:54:39 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:The remote host forcibly broke off existing connection
[2013-09-13 14:54:40 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1

Comment: if you are running windows, you may need some drivers ? what device are you using ?

Comment: yes W7. I create one virtual device and tested apps on them. If I pressed ctrl + F11 on DDMS tab saw emulator in devices. But I can see the connected device.

Comment: Run > Debug Configuration > Target > Always promt selection mode
Connect my android phone to PC, debbuger mode is active.
Press F11 in eclipse and there is no rows in "Choose the running Android device"

Comment: what is your device ?